# Converting managed Byte array to unmanaged string

Tags: c++, c++-cli, unmanaged-memory

I am trying to convert a managed byte array to std::string in my C++/CLI wrapper; however, I am seeing some corrupt memory in the heap later on.  Just wanted to check if I am doing the conversion right.  Below is my method is CLI:

```
string ByteArrayToStr(array<Byte>^ byteArray)
{
    int size = byteArray.Length;
    IntPtr pnt = Marshal::AllocHGlobal(size + 1);
    char* chararray = (char*)pnt.ToPointer();
    try
    {
        Marshal::Copy(byteArray, 0, pnt, size);
        *(chararray + size) = 0;
        return string(chararray);
    }
    finally
    {
        Marshal::FreeHGlobal(pnt);
    }
}
```

Does anything seem wrong in above code?

Comment: I don't see any problems in that code. I would change the second line in the `try` block to use `chararray[site]`, but that would be just more readable, it wouldn't change what the code does.

Comment: You don't typically need a lot of help from C++/CLI code to corrupt the heap.  This isn't it.

Comment: Thank you for the validation.  There must be some bug my code elsewhere; I shall take a look.  Thank you, Raj.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are doing an unnecessary explicit copy and playing with a manual memory allocation.

You could just pass the raw pinned pointer to `std::string` constructor:

```
string ByteArrayToStr(array<Byte>^ byteArray)
{
    pin_ptr<unsigned char> temp = &byteArray[0];
    return string(reinterpret_cast<char*>(temp), byteArray->Length);
}
```

Comment: That's definitely much simpler. I believe the 'str' in the second line was a typo though. Thank you.

Comment: BTW, pin_ptr goes out of scope when the function returns.  Does std::string constructor do the copying of managed data pointed to by 'temp' into unmanaged data so that the returned string can be used later?

Comment: @user392005 Yes, `std::string` copies the data in its own internal buffer.